# Remove first part of a line until character @ is found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have an email list like so:

```
aaa@you1.com
abc@you3.com
def@you4.com
```

I need to remove all the characters that precede the @ symbol. Is there a method of doing this with Sed?

Comment: "Until" including the `@` or not? That is, do you want "@you1.com" as input or just "you1.com"?

Comment: your help is right ,i want @you1.com.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ sed 's/[^@]*//' file
@you1.com
@you3.com
@you4.com
```

The basic sed syntax is `sed 's/search/replace/' file`. This looks for `search` in `file` and replaces it with `replace` text. In case you want to perform this replacement in all matches of the line, then you can use `sed 's/search/replace/g' file`.

In this case we are looking for the pattern `[^@]*`, which means: all characters that are not `@`. This will match the very beginning of a line until (excluded) a `@` is found. Replacing with `//` means that this string will be replaced with nothing -> removed.

To do an in-place editing, just add `-i.bak`. This way, your original file will be replaced but a backup `file.bak` will be created as well:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[^@]*//' file
```

Comment: assuming that line without @ will be blank (if any)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu for that case we could filter initially with `sed '/@/s/[^@]*//' file`

Answer (score 5):

```
sed 's/^.*@/@/' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use grep,

```
$ grep -oE '@.*' file
@you1.com
@you3.com
@you4.com
```